# How to create object of image in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-functional-component

I want to get rendered height and width of the image before loading so I have created an object of image and trying to get height, width by onload method.

Below is my code snippet:

```
var imgUrl = "https://www.sammobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/keyguard_default_wallpaper_green-405x405.png";
var imgHeight = 0;
var imgWidth = 0;
var Im = new Image();
Im.src = imgUrl;
Im.onload = () => (imgHeight = Im.height);
```

But I am getting an error while creating the image object.

> Image is not a constructor

How can I investigate this?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have enough points to comment but there is nothing wrong with your snippet.

[image]

checked [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) and it’s very good.

You don’t have this API for some reason, might worth check your bundler for answers.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @mstrk there's nothing wrong with your script, however, if your runtime (your browser) somehow doesn't know how to construct the image via `new Image()` you can create one via

```
document.createElement('img')
```

Here's the snippet printing width / height in the console when image loads

```
var imgUrl = "https://www.sammobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/keyguard_default_wallpaper_green-405x405.png";
var imgHeight = 0;
var imgWidth = 0;
var Im = document.createElement('img');
Im.src = imgUrl;
Im.onload = () => {
  imgHeight = Im.height;
  imgWidth = Im.width;
  console.log(imgWidth, imgHeight);
}
```

Comment: It's worked, thank you bro but it's giving me image's original height and width, i want to get render image resolution(aspect ratio). is it possible?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by original width/height (zeros?). Could be that you are trying to read them before `onload` happens. I updated the answer with a code sample.